# Pause and resume handler in Android

Tags: android

How can I write some codes in `Onresume` or `Onpause` status in Android Studio?

How I can do this? With which codes?

Comment: In Onresume and Onpause you can write what you want

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin Can you write codes with answer?

Comment: Are you coding in Kotlin?

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin No, I code with Java.

Comment: Do you have problem that I send you code in Kotlin?

Comment: I can help by uploading the code you tried.

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin Ok. Yes. Please send the codes.

Comment: @Genesis Ok. Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 import android.os.Bundle
    import android.os.PersistableBundle
    import android.util.Log
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity


    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
            Log.d("abc", "oncreate")
        }

        override fun onPause() {
            super.onPause()
            Log.d("abc", "onpause")
        }

        override fun onResume() {
            super.onResume()
            Log.d("abc", "onresume")
        }
    }
```

Here is simple code and you can see in your logcat in what status your app is.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will run onpause function when I would pause handler?

Comment: In your AVD or mobile that you test your app, you can see in logcat when app is in onresume and when is onpause, you can do what you want in any of the statuses.